# Every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My teacher gave us this exercise to think, she'll do it tomorrow on class (I hope). I've been thinking but I don't know how to start, if somebody could give me a hint, I would appreciate so much:

> Prove that every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: what are the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Hint: first of all is better if you convince yourself with some examples, e.g. $n=2,3,4...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $H \leq \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ be a subgroup, take the smallest positive $a \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a \in H$.

(Note by $a \in H$ I really mean $a + n\mathbb Z \in H$, but it's common to just write $a \in H$)

Answer (score 2):

Subgroups of $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ correspond, by inverse image by the canonical projection $\mathbf{Z}\to \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$, to subgroups of $\mathbf{Z}$ containing $n\mathbf{Z}$, that is, as $\mathbf{Z}$'s subgroups are cyclic, to subgroups $d\mathbf{Z}$ such that $d|n$, so that subgroups of $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ are of the form $d\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$, with $d|n$. Finally, note that $d\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ is but the sub-group of $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ generated by the image of $d$ in $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$, a cyclic group.

Comment: @OP [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_theorem) for this result, known as the lattice theorem, correspondance theorem or fourth isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @BillDubuque Ugly names, isn't it ? ;-) Only "correspondance theorem" would be tolerable. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Every subgroup $H ⊂ ℤ/nℤ$ is finite. If $x_1, …, x_d ∈ ℤ$ represent all elements of $H$, then consider $x = \gcd (x_1, …, x_d)$. Now answer these questions (with a proof):

- Does $x$ represent an element of $H$?
- How can you express the elements of $H$ in terms of $[x]_{nℤ}$?

Answer (score 1):

It is no harder to show a more general result: Any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Then as $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, you have your answer and a more general result to boot!

To show this, suppose the original cyclic group is generated by $g$. Then for some power $n$, $g^n$ must be in your subgroup. Take the smallest such $n$. Then show that $g^n$ must generate your subgroup. To do this, you will want to make use of the division algorithm:

> If m and n are integers and n is positive, then there are unique integers q and r such that m=nq+r and 0≤r